# Usb boot failure.Result "Grub rescue"

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, grub, rescue

I have ubuntu studio and want to install Windows 10 completely (not dual booting). But when I try to make a bootable pen drive I am failing for a long time. I had used WinUsb for the installation of W10 iso. But when I boot from the pen drive I am bought to Grub rescue. I have all the files in pen drive but booting is a problem. Don't try to suggest me about CD as my CD ROM drive is not working.I have ubuntu if needed for fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Always install the windows OS before installing the Linux OS because the windows OS bootloader is designed in such that it overwrites the all previous bootloader's/grub by a new windows bootloader. So first install windows then try to install Linux based OS.

Comment: I Am going to remove ubuntu. My problem is the boot failure of pen drive. If you can suggest me how to install bootloader of setup of Windows please do.